Store data from XML into database
I want to create a database to store forex exchange rates using this code into PostgreSQL:
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);

System.out.println(response.getBody());

I'm not sure wat table structure should be the best option to use. The only model for now that I can think of is:



currency
rate
date




EUR
1.21
2011-11-2


JPY
2.11
2011-11-2


GBP
1.3
2011-11-2


CAD
2.1
2011-11-2


EUR
1.21
2012-11-2


JPY
2.11
2012-11-2


GBP
1.3
2012-11-2


CAD
2.1
2012-11-2



Is it better to use for example direct store of a XML file into database or there is a better more optimized way?

For a database like PostgreSQL, it's faster to store the different records (like you do in your proposal) instead of a complete XML object. Searching data in this object is relatively slow, even when using indexes.

What's wrong with that table structure? That is exactly how we store exchange rates in our database.

The table structure you presented efficiently captures the contents of the elements in the XML response. The following code demonstrates an approach using curl to retrieve the current daily exchange rates and XMLTABLE to process the returned XML.
It's best not to use SQL keywords as column identifiers, so the date is stored as exchange_date:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exchange_rates (
  exchange_date DATE,
  currency TEXT,
  rate NUMERIC,
  PRIMARY KEY (exchange_date, currency)
);

The following SQL retrieves the daily exchange rates from the URL and inserts them into exchange_rates:
-- ensure that there is a temporary table to hold the response from the URL
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS forex_response (
  id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  response_line TEXT
);

-- ensure that any prior responses have been cleared
TRUNCATE TABLE forex_response;

-- use an external program to read from the URL (the delimiter was chosen
-- to minimize the risk of inadvertently splitting a response line into 
-- multiple columns)
COPY forex_response (response_line)
FROM PROGRAM 'curl https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml'
WITH (FORMAT TEXT, DELIMITER E'\01');

WITH
  -- convert the response lines into an XML document
  x AS (SELECT STRING_AGG(response_line, '' ORDER BY id)::XML AS response
          FROM forex_response)
INSERT INTO exchange_rates(exchange_date, currency, rate)
SELECT
  r.exchange_date, r.currency, r.rate
FROM
  XMLTABLE(
    XMLNAMESPACES (
      'http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01' AS gesmes,
      'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref' AS b
    ),
    '/gesmes:Envelope/b:Cube/b:Cube/b:Cube'
    PASSING (SELECT x.response FROM x)
    COLUMNS
      rate NUMERIC PATH '@rate',
      exchange_date DATE PATH '../@time',
      currency TEXT PATH '@currency') r
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

To populate exchange_rates with historical values instead of the current day's values, use the following URLs:
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml
These URLs return all available historical values, or only those for the past 90 days (respectively).
